# How to select a complete node in forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In 3dsMax I can select a node,The result of selection is in this picture
[3ds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVBUS.png),But when I convert this model to svf format and select it in the forge viewer, it only selects part of it,like this [forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPhtI.png)
I don't know why this happens,Can someone tell me why this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer has a default selection behavior where - when you click on something in the viewport - it will typically try to select the lower most node in the hierarchy. You should still be able to select an arbitrary node in the *Model Browser* window, or programmatically using `viewer.select([nodeId1, nodeId2, ...])`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the dbid of a sibling node, because when I click on a device I only get the device dbId and then isolate the dbid, so it looks like this

Comment: Sure, you can iterate the hierarchy tree up and down using the [InstanceTree](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Private/InstanceTree/) object, for example: `let tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree(); tree.getNodeParentId(dbId); tree.getChildCount(dbId); tree.enumNodeChildren(node, callback, recursive);` etc.